# non-identity column auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a project to consolidate data (from 2 different DBs).  I have created a table that contains a few columns:

- MAPPING_ID int
- ContentID int
- ContentValue varchar(200)

For Example, when I do my 1st set of inserts against the original data source everything is good.

```
Mapping_ID: 53
ContentID: 53
ContentValue: Original Data 1

Mapping_ID: 54
ContentID: 54
ContentValue: Original Data 2
```

But when I do my second set of inserts against the another source (the data I'm trying to merge) I would like the Mapping_ID column to continue to the next number (i.e. 55,56,57...)

I looked at the `row_number` function but that starts at 1.  **Is there a way to start it at 55?**

I suppose I could make that Mapping_ID column an Identity field, but turn it off during the first insert and then seed it with the max value (54) and then turn it on during the second insert.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Nicarus - SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Why not just `row_number() + 54` ?

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov - 2012

Comment: @Blorgbeard - row_number() +54 doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.  It needs and Over clause.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - but this works: (row_number() over(order by (select 1)) + 54)

Comment: Yes, I just didn't feel like typing the whole thing out. Just add 54 to the whole thing

Comment: @Blorgbeard - if you wanted to put that as an answer I'll mark it as such.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `row_number()` to start at 55, you could just add 54 (or whatever number) to your `row_number()` calculation:

```
(row_number() over (partition by Y order by X)) + 54
```

Comment: @sgeddes oops, I always forget that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012+, you may use [SEQUENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) objects to populate non-identity columns with autoincrement values. Plus you may use same SEQUENCE for different tables to make numeration pass-through and obtain values from sequences in SELECT and UPDATE queries.

First, create SEQUENCE:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SchemaName.SequenceName
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Then, create DEFAULT constraint with [values from sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370(v=sql.110).aspx) on required column:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_unique_name DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SchemaName.SequenceName FOR Mapping_ID;
```

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov Have you tried your solution by adding `WITH VALUES` at the end to modify existing rows? The previous rows remain NULL. I didn't see any documentation indicating that `NEXT VALUE FOR` doesn't apply to already existing rows. However, an article, [SQL Server SEQUENCE Basics by Joe Celko](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/), indicates that: "The `NEXT VALUE FOR` function is not allowed in `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statements."

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a brand new way to do this kind of thing as of SQL Server 2012: the sequence object. I'm sorry I can't script out a procedure for you as I'm working in the MySQL world at present, but it's super easy to implement. The basic idea is you're maintaining a separate database object with its own seed and increment amount, but there are some caveats to bear in mind regarding their difference from traditional identity values (e.g. you can overwrite them), so make sure you do some research.

Here are a couple of articles to get you started. If you have trouble, hit me back and I'll try to work through the code with you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I'll check it out.